# String as file name in C++ Outfile

Tags: c++, string, file-io, ofstream

can someone please tell me why the following won't work?

```
#include <fstream.h>  
#include <iostream.h>

std::string data, newtitle, body;
ofstream outfile;

int main()
{
   cout << "enter body of note: ";
   cin >> body;

   cout << "enter title of note: ";
   cin >> newtitle;

   data =  newtitle + ".dat";

   outfile.open(data, ios::out);
   outfile << body << endl;
   outfile.close();               

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

The problem seems to be stemming from the attempt to combine `newtitle` and `.dat`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First,

```
#include <fstream.h>
```

is wrong, it should just be

```
#include <fstream>
```

And ditto for the other header.

Second, you need to

```
#include <string>
```

to use `std::string`.

Third, if you're compiling for C++03 then there's no constructor taking a `std::string`. However this was fixed in C++11.

---

Tip #1:
You don't need `system( "pause" )`. In Visual Studio simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to run the program. Then the console window keeps.

Or, just run the program from the command line.

---

Tip #2:
You can avoid a lot of trouble by declaring variables as close to first use as possible. For example, by moving `std::string data, newtitle, body;` into `main`, and with each declared as late as possible, you ensure that no other code messes with these variables, and that it's entirely clear what the initial values are, etc.

---

Tip #3:
You don't need a `return 0;` at the end of `main`: it's the default.

Comment: @pezy: The C++ language is defined by an international ISO standard. It does cost money, so it can't be linked to directly. But you can download a draft (drafts are free) from the committee pages, or you can look at e.g. (http://cppreference.com), although that's second-hand information, and thus not so reliable. Re "good practice", I think so, because IMO every practice that simplifies the code is good. The explicit `return 0` indicates the possibility of returning something else, which is misleading for most beginners' programs. Adding misleading text is IMO ungood. I.e. removing it is good.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I read the draft(N3690), It said: "If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the eﬀect is that of executing `return 0;`"(3.6.1.5). I don't know that before. thx again.

Answer (score 0):

**std::cin** separates input string by **whitespace**

if you input this text to the 1st cin

> abc def

body variable will be **abc**, and newtitle will be **def**. In this case, std::getline might be the answer